# Can transformer secondary side noise couple back to the primary side?

Tags: transformer

As this picture:

[image]

Basically, only the noise of primary side will be coupled to secondary side.

I read this wiki and know of leakage flux in the secondary side.

If the secondary side has noise current such as switch power, can secondary side noise be coupled to the primary side by leakage flux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformer coupling between primary and secondary windings is mutual and given by a coupling constant (between 0 and 1), which tells you how much of the flux going through one winding will *also* go through the other winding.

Transformers are built such as to maximize the coupling constant at the working frequency, e.g. 10 kHz to a few MHz for SMPS transformers.

Depending on the core material, the coupling constant can change dramatically with frequency, because:

- the real permeability of the core material can deteriorate at high frequencies
- the imaginary permeability (loss) can rise at high frequencies, which is *exploited* in transformers such as common-mode chokes or in ferrite beads

Therefore, it is possible and even likely that high frequency switching noise - far beyond the working frequency - is coupled inefficiently between the windings by design. But this depends on the core material. A 50 Hz iron transformer will have quite strong attenuation at very high frequencies, while a small SMPS transformer might show rather little core loss even at 100 MHz. In general, there will be some noise feedthrough, if not magnetically through the core, then at least capacitively through the windings. So you still need proper conducted emission filtering, but you can save on magnetic filtering components if you have the right transformer.

Comment: Ok, so Could I understand as: 2nd secondary can propagate back noise to prime side, but through low pass filter?

Comment: @curlywei yes kind of. But it is not a 20dB/decade rolloff as from a real filter but instead the coupling efficiency just somehow drops..But really the difference is in the core materials and can be like night and day.

Answer (score 2):

The leakage flux doesn't magnetically couple the windings. The main flux does. And the noise in either winding will be reflected to the other winding via the main flux.

So yes, if the transformer secondary is connected to a noisy switching converter, then the current noise and voltage spikes will happily propagate to the primary.

The transformer has to be treated as if it was a transparent bidirectional current/voltage scaling element - because it is. The core losses may dissipate some higher frequencies, but that's not a magical fix by any means.